# How to describe the many-to-many sql relation in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I've create genres and books tables in mysql database

```
create table genres
(
  gID varchar(20) not null,
  gName varchar(100) not null,
  primary key(gID)
);


create table books
(
  ISBN varchar(20) not null,
  BookTitle varchar(255) not null,
  Description text,
  PageCount int not null,
  Rating  numeric(3, 2),
  Language varchar(20),
  CoverImage varchar(255),
  Price numeric(5, 2),
  PublishedDate date,
  publisher_pID varchar(20) not null,
  VoteCount int default 0,
  primary key(ISBN),
  foreign key(publisher_pID) references publishers(pID)
);

create table books_genres
(
  Book_ISBN varchar(20) not null,
  Genre_gID varchar(20) not null,
  primary key(Book_ISBN, Genre_gID),
  foreign key(Book_ISBN) references books(ISBN) on delete cascade,
  foreign key(Genre_gID) references genres(gID) on delete cascade
);
```

I imported them in django using "**python manage.py inspectdb > models.py**", and then performed all the needed migrations. The imported models(edited a little bit):

```
class Genres(models.Model):
    gid = models.CharField(db_column='gID', primary_key=True, max_length=20)  # Field name made lowercase.
    gname = models.CharField(db_column='gName', max_length=100)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Genres"
        db_table = 'genres'


class Books(models.Model):
    isbn = models.CharField(db_column='ISBN', primary_key=True, max_length=20)  # Field name made lowercase.
    booktitle = models.CharField(db_column='BookTitle', max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
    description = models.TextField(db_column='Description', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pagecount = models.IntegerField(db_column='PageCount')  # Field name made lowercase.
    rating = models.DecimalField(db_column='Rating', max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    language = models.CharField(db_column='Language', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    coverimage = models.CharField(db_column='CoverImage', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    price = models.DecimalField(db_column='Price', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    publisheddate = models.DateField(db_column='PublishedDate', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    publisher_pid = models.ForeignKey(Publishers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='publisher_pID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    votecount = models.IntegerField(db_column='VoteCount', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Books"
        db_table = 'books'


class BooksGenres(models.Model):
    book_isbn = models.ForeignKey(Books, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='Book_ISBN', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    genre_gid = models.ForeignKey(Genres, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='Genre_gID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Books_Genres"
        db_table = 'books_genres'
        unique_together = (('book_isbn', 'genre_gid'),)
```

Now, the problem is in the many-to-many relation table of books and genres. Django doesn't support more than one key. But my database contains more than 4000 relations. **Each book has more than one genres(max. 10).**

The server runs fine but when I try to access the Books_Genre models (image attached below) in django admin page. It returns **MultipleObjectsReturned** error:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /admin/first_app/booksgenres/9507399194/change/
get() returned more than one BooksGenres -- it returned 8!
```

Image : [Django-admin site snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW0sj.png)

I can easily see all the genres (say of isbn = 9507399194) in mysql by running the command:

```
SELECT
  isbn,
  BookTitle,
  gName AS genreCount
FROM books
JOIN books_genres
  ON books.isbn = books_genres.book_isbn
JOIN genres
  ON genres.gid = books_genres.genre_gid
WHERE isbn = 9507399194;
```

OUTPUT:

```
+------------+---------------+---------------------+
| isbn       | BookTitle     | genreCount          |
+------------+---------------+---------------------+
| 9507399194 | Fuenteovejuna | Classics            |
| 9507399194 | Fuenteovejuna | Plays               |
| 9507399194 | Fuenteovejuna | Fiction             |
| 9507399194 | Fuenteovejuna | Academic            |
| 9507399194 | Fuenteovejuna | Drama               |
| 9507399194 | Fuenteovejuna | Literature          |
| 9507399194 | Fuenteovejuna | Cultural            |
| 9507399194 | Fuenteovejuna | European Literature |
+------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

So how to deal with MultipleObjectsReturned in Django. Do I need to make some changes in table definition of books_genres?

I read about ManytomanyField on Django but can't understand how to apply on it. Please help me out, other things are working properly as I can access other tables on the django-admin site

Comment: The composed primary key is your problem. Primary key composed of multiple key are generally inconvenient to say it at its mildest. It might be a good idea to add a kind of auto increment field as the primary key. Like Django does when it is creating the database.

Comment: I was also thinking that idea for the last choice. So adding a primary key(auto_increment) in the relation table Books_Genres is the only option??

Comment: You are free to have your own priorities, but for me a composed primary key would be the last option.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Also can you please tell me or share some useful links for the joins in Django I need to perform like I performed in sql, joining three tables etc

Comment: You don't join in Django, the ORM joins for you.